# Retrieve user paths in universal windows app

Tags: c#, windows-10, uwp

I just created an universal windows app project in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10. What I want is retrieve user paths from environment variables, namely: `APPDATA` and `USERPROFILE`.

I tried using `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(string)`, but it does not work (returns `null`). Then when debugging I called `System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables().Count` and it returns `0`!

I tried doing the same thing on a classic desktop app, and the methods work as intended.

I wonder if it's my system settings, or there is some kind of restrictions for windows apps? If the API is restricted, how am I supposed to read/write into `APPDATA`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to look at the classes in the [`Windows.Storage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230562.aspx) namespace.

Specifically, look at [`ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx) and [`ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx).

For the Documents folder, use [`KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.knownfolders.documentslibrary.aspx).

Comment: I get an `UnauthorizedAcessException` when calling `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary`

Comment: The MSDN links explain what you need to do (and probably shouldn't do).